# InAppPurchases.connectAsync() returning error code

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase, expo

I'm just ejected my Expo project from a managed workflow to the bare workflow. I'm currently trying to implement InAppPurchases: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/in-app-purchases/

However, I noticed 2 things:

1. `connectAsync` returns an error code
2. `getProductsAsync` hangs

Here is where I call `connectAsync` and then `getProductsAsync`:

```
  const getProducts = async () => {
    console.log("all response codes: ", IAPResponseCode);
    const history = await InAppPurchases.connectAsync();
    console.log("connect async:", history);

    const items = Platform.select({
      ios: ["cloemonthly", "cloeanually"],
      android: ["cloemonthly", "cloeanually"],
    });

    console.log("before get products");
    const { responseCode, results } = await InAppPurchases.getProductsAsync(
      items
    ); // <------------------------------------------------ HANGS HERE
    console.log("after get products");

    if (responseCode === IAPResponseCode.OK) {
      setProducts(results);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getProducts();
  }, []);
```

When I refresh the app, it prints this:

```
LOG  all response codes:  {"0": "OK", "1": "USER_CANCELED", "2": "ERROR", "3": "DEFERRED", "DEFERRED": 3, "ERROR": 2, "OK": 0, "USER_CANCELED": 1}
       LOG  connect async: {"errorCode": 0, "responseCode": 2, "results": []}
       LOG  before get products
```

As you can see, connectAsync returns an error and it hangs on getProductsAsync

I believe I have the proper set up in Xcode and on ItunesConnect

[image]

[image]

What else am I missing?

Comment: in app purchases only work on real devices, you need to fix your provisioning profile.

Comment: Yeh you’re right I ran it on a device and fixed my profile and it worked